# Re-declaration of the same static variable inside a function

Tags: php, static

I have such a function, and I declare the **same static variable twice with different values**. Then, I called the function, but the result surprised me.

```
function question(){
    static $a=1;
    $a++;
    echo $a; // output:?
    static $a=10;
    $a++;
    echo $a; // output:?
}
```

I thought the outputs would be: `2 11`, but the outputs was: `11 12`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare and initialize the same static variable *more than once* inside a function, then the variable will take the value of the *last* declaration (static declarations are resolved in compile-time.)

In this case, the static variable of `$a` will take the value of `10` in the compile time, ignoring the value of `1` in the previous same declaration.

Comment: Okay,if I declare same static local variables in different functions , will it affect with each other?

Comment: For the record: In the implementation language of PHP, [the C language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)), the redefinition is a fatal error, but PHP handles it as described above.

Comment: Thank you for the rigor and patience ：）

Answer (score 0):

Static works the same way as it does in a class. 
The variable is shared across all instances of a function.
so if you initialize same static variable many time then it will always take latest value.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable exists only in the declared local function scope, but it does not lose its value when program execution leaves this scope.
The use of Static keyword is itself such that it will not lose track of the current count.
So In your case, function execution stops at $a = 10; $a++;
Hence you have 11 and 12 as output.
If you want output to be 2 and 11; keep only one declaration static like below.

```
function question(){
    $a=1;
    $a++;
    echo $a; // output:?
    static $a=10;
    $a++;
    echo $a; // output:?
}
```